# What is the difference between passing arguments to initialize and setting them within initialize?

Tags: ruby

I would like to know the difference between passing arguments in parentheses to `initialize` vs setting those values manually in `initialize`?

```
class CashRegister
  attr_accessor :items, :discount, :total, :last_transaction

  def initialize(discount=0)
    @total = 0
    @discount = discount
    @items = []
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that by putting it in the arguments, you allow the caller to provide different values, versus hard-coding them. For example:

```
def initialize(discount=0, total=0, items=[])
  @total = total
  @discount = discount
  @items = items
end
```

Now you can call it with no arguments, or you can specify the arguments:

```
MyClass.new
# uses all defaults

MyClass.new(123)
# Uses custom value for discount only

MyClass.new(1, 2, ["item"])
# Uses custom values for all
```

The problem with this approach, is what happens when you want to give a custom value for total (the second argument) but use the default value for discount (the first)? With positional arguments, you can't. So it's preferred to use keyword arguments instead:

```
def initialize(discount: 0, total: 0, items: [])
```

Now you can specify custom values for any combination of the three arguments, for example:

```
MyClass.new
# uses all defaults

MyClass.new(total: 123)
# this uses default values for discount and items
```

Comment: Hello Max, Great Explanation thanks. What if it's the other way around? If it's in the body but not in the argument.

Comment: @DmitriyMalayev then the value will always be the same, when you call `MyClass.new` they will always have the same value and there won't be a way to change that